# If $\alpha$ , $\beta$ are roots of the quadratic equation $x^2 -2p(x-4) -15 = 0$ , then answer the following .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

What is the set of of values of $p$ for which one root is less than $1$ and the other is greater than $2$ ?

A) $ (7/3,\infty) $

B) $ (-\infty,7/3) $

C) $ x \in R $

D) $ None $

Please tell me whats wrong with each of my approach :

**My Approach 1 :**

$ \alpha \in (-\infty,1) $  & $ \beta \in (2,\infty) $

$\implies -\infty + 2 < \alpha + \beta < 1+\infty $

$\implies \alpha + \beta \in R $ $\implies p \in R $

Now D > 0 , for two distinct roots . => ( p - 3 ) ( p - 5 ) > 0

$ \implies p \in ( -\infty , 3 ) \cup ( 5 , \infty ) $

**My Approach 2:**

$ \alpha \in (-\infty,1) $  & $ \beta \in (2,\infty) $

*from equation*

$ \alpha + \beta = 2p \implies \alpha = 2p - \beta $

$\alpha \cdot \beta = 8p - 15 $

$\implies ( 2p - \beta ) \cdot ( \beta ) = 8p - 15 $

$\implies p = {{\beta^2 - 15}\over {2\beta - 8}} $

Now how do I find p from this using b > 2 ?!!

**The answer is (B)**

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of mistakes in your attempt, so I'm just going to show you a new method.

Let $y(x)=x^2-2px+8p-15$ . Then our quadratic equation is simply $y=0$. You probably know that if you plot the graph of $y$ against $x$, it will be an upward opening parabola. The roots of $y=0$ will simply be the abcissa of the points where the parabola cuts the X-axis.

Now for two real roots, $D>0$ so we have $4p^2>4(8p-15)\tag{i}$

Also if one root is less than 1 and the other is greater than 2 then you can imagine that the parabola will go below the X-axis for the entire interval $[1,2]$

Mathematically, we write this as $y(1)<0$ and $y(2)<0$ which gives us two more inequalities in $p$:

$$6p-14<0\tag{ii}$$
$$4p-11<0\tag{iii}$$
If you find the solution sets of the three inequalities obtained their intersection will be the final solution.

Comment: For the roots to be real, shouldn't D be greater than or equal to 0?

Comment: how u concluded that the parabola will be an upward opening?

Comment: @Mick you were right, thanks. I've corrected it.

Comment: @Daga the coefficient of $x^2$ is positive, so the second derivative is positive, so the parabola is upward opening or concave.